# Formula to indicate if at least one value from a column is not lookuping

Tags: excel

I have a column B with different values i.e.

```
ad3
sf5
4ff
s44
4ff
4ff
4ff
gt5
```

In cell A1 I need to indicate if at least one of those values can't be vlookup'ed from another column.
I have to do it in A1 with a formula (can't just vlookup every value in column C and search for errors).
I can't use VBA.

Do you think this is possible? How should this formula look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have data in Columns B and C like below:

[image]

In Cell A1, enter this formula:

`=ISERROR(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(B1:B8,C1:C8,0)))`

It will return **TRUE** if any of the values in Column B is not available in Column C.
So for above, it will return **TRUE** since **s44** is not found in Column C. 
Is this what you're trying? Else, might want to answer pnuts queries above. HTH.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! A very simple and elegant solution :] Thank you!